# Replacing light switches-- can all live / all neutral wires be grouped? Is conduit a valid ground?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, home-automation

I'm replacing two switches (which control separate lights) in a two-gang box with two smart switches (TP-Link HS200). To make my questions as clear as possible, I've sketched the current state as well as my plan for the smart switches:

**Current State:**

[image: Current State]

**Future State:**

[image: Final Stalte]

My questions are as follows:

1. Does the future state look okay? Can I group all live and all neutral wires together per my plan?
2. I live in Cook County, which requires conduit. Does this mean I can attach the grounds from the smart switches right into the 2-gang box and that's all I need?
3. The smart switches don't distinguish between a line/load. Will they just figure this out? Or do I need to make sure I use the same one as a line/load for each since they'll be connected?
4. Any guesses as to what the other orange/load wire is running up to? This room only has two lights, but I don't want to interfere.

Thank you for any advice you can provide-- as I'm sure is apparent, this is my first time with this!

Comment: In your second diagram one of the red wires should be black. (Either that, or in your first diagram the black wire should be red.)

Comment: It is not clear from your diagrams whether power enters via the orange wire at the bottom or via the orange wire at the top -- but it doesn't matter because you're not changing either one.

Comment: Hi-- you're correct, on the second diagram the one on the right should be black. My mistake! And I believe power enters from the bottom since the lights are on the ceiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions in turn:

1. Your future state with all the always-hots nutted together and all the neutrals nutted together looks spot-on, yes.
2. You are correct -- metal conduit is a valid equipment grounding conductor (always has been and pretty much always will be save for some extreme circumstances that don't show up in residential work), so grounding to a metal box works in your case.  Make sure to use a 10-32 machine screw into the matching hole on the box (vs. one of the mounting holes, which won't be tapped properly for this) -- you can get a bag of pre-made-up grounding-screw-pigtails, even.
3. They're behaving like a normal switch here, so they'll figure this out on their own I reckon.
4. That other orange wire is simply an always-hot running to some other switch, receptacle, or outlet on the circuit, likely in some other room.

Comment: Both ThreePhaseEel and Harper are correct. Little known fact NEC 250.126 will tell you the ground screw must be green. This doesn't make  a ground less of a ground but if an inspector (AHJ) sees it he may flag it. Also, we used to use the conduit as a ground all of the time back in the 1970's and 1980's and it is still legal, but if the AHJ is younger he may be more comfortable if you run a ground wire since it is intrinsically safe and make you go that direction.

Answer (score 1):

1 You are using orange for always-hot.  That is a fine choice*.   Yes, that grouping of all always-hots (orange) together is correct.  Ditto all neutrals (white).

2 If the box and all connecting conduit is metal and non-flexible, the conduit is a valid grounding path.  You are always allowed to double it with a ground *wire* if you worry about the conduit's integrity, however the cause of your worry might be a code violation.

As far as attaching the grounds to "an empty screw hole", nope! Using a nail, wood screw or sheet metal screw is right out.  You must attach the grounds to **a very particular screw hole**, specifically the one threaded 10-32, and you must use a 10-32 screw to do it.  You can also drill and tap your own hole 10-32, or if you have access, you can use a nut and bolt to same effect.  Home Depot sells cute little green 10-32 ground screws, with or without pigtails already attached.

3 you must obey the instructions when installing the smart switches.  I don't find it terribly surprising that a smart switch doesn't care which is line hot and which is load hot.  It only takes 1 extra diode and simplifies field installation.

4 Anytime you see an an always-hot and neutral exiting together on the load side, that simply means this is not the only load in the circuit.  In the case of Romex switch loops, that hot+neutral is going to a future smart switch.

5 I would not make *both* switched-hot wires the same color.  You will lose your mind. That's why there are 8 colors for hots: black brown red orange yellow pink blue and violet.

---

* unless you are coming out of a 240V 3-phase wild-leg delta panel: in that case, orange is reserved for the wild leg.  That is the only place in the entire NEC where it calls out a specific color for a hot.  Other than that, it only prohibits green white and gray.